# Images not showing when deployed to github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, github

I am having aan issue with the deployed version of my app on github pages, I am getting broken images

github pages link: https://moeabraham.github.io/module-1-proj/
github link : https://github.com/moeabraham/module-1-proj

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `/` on image tag.
removing this from the beginning should work.

You currently have this:

```js
<img src="/images/juve.svg" class="rounded static-img" name="juventus">
```

Use this instead:

```js
<img src="images/juve.svg" class="rounded static-img" name="juventus">
```